# After padding a string with zeroes - it prints unspecified characters? (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

Basically, here, I'm trying to reverse an array, and convert the reversed int array into a string (I'm trying to write the equivalent of Java's BigInteger class in C++ - basically turning the input into big endian ordering, breaking down the operations, reversing the result back to little endian format, and returning the string).

And as you can see below, it outputs some strange characters (I think it's an out of range reference?) - but I'm not entirely sure what caused this output?

I would really appreciate if you could take a look at it:

**Sample input**

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
int rA[3];

reverseIntArray(a, rA, 3);
string aString = intArrayToString(a, 3);

cout << aString << endl;
```

**Console output**

```
123\216\377
```

As you can see - it calculates the answer correctly, with the exception of the `\277_\377`.

I'll post the rest of the relevant functions:

**reverseIntArray**

```
void reverseIntArray(int array[], int reversedArray[], int arrayLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        reversedArray[i] = array[arrayLength - 1 - i];
    }
}
```

**intArrayToString**

```
string intArrayToString(int digits[], int length) {
    //  convert int array to char array
    char digitsChar[length];


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        digitsChar[i] = '0' + digits[i];
    }

    //  convert char array to string
    string intString(digitsChar);

    return intString;
}
```

I'm quite sure this is a subtle issue to do with pointers, but I'm still relatively new to C++ (migrating from Java) and I've stared at this for hours but haven't come up with any ideas.

Comment: If you have three characters in a string, you need an array of length 4 (one extra for the terminating NULL character). Instead of using an array, why not just work directly with a `std::string`?

Comment: By the way, your code is technically not valid C++, as C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: @crashmstr I'm trying to write a BigInteger class in C++ - all of the operations involve me dealing with the two strings one char at a time - I thought it would be easier to store the result as an int array instead of a string array - but if you have an alternative - I'm all ears. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm confused...where did I use variable length arrays?

Comment: @CodeApprentice In the declaration of `digitsChar`.

Comment: @CodeApprentice `char digitsChar[length];` when `length` is not a constant expression is not standard C++, but a compiler extension supported by some compilers. As far as what I was talking about with arrays, your `char` array `digitsChar` is too small to hold 3 characters and still be a valid C string (no room for null terminator). Has nothing to do with your `int` arrays!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hmm I still don't understand - by declaring an array of a fixed length - doesn't that make it a fixed length array? Oh...after reading crashmstr 's answer - do you mean that if it's not explicitly a constant number e.g. int array[3], then it is invalid C++?

Comment: The array size need to be a compile-time constant, it must be known when the source is compiled. `length` is obviously not a compile-time constant (and no, making it `const` doesn't make it so). Though some compilers allows this as am extension to the C++ language.

Comment: Ah my bad - I was imprecise with semantics - but I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you are using is assuming that the string you pass is properly terminated, which it isn't and that leads to *undefined behavior* as the `std::string` constructor goes beyond the end of the `digitsChar` array.

Three possible solutions:

1. Make room for another character in the `digitsChar` array and terminate it:

   ```
   char digitsChar[size + 1];

   for (...) { ... }

   digitsChar[3] = '\0';

   string intString(digitsChar);
   ```
2. Use another constructor where you pass the length of the character array:

   ```
   string intString(digitsChar, length);
   ```
3. Append the characters directly to the string:

   ```
   string intString;

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       intString += '0' + digits[i];
   }
   ```

There are of course other solutions as well, like for example using [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: I liked the first solution the best - one I"m most familiar with seeing I think - thanks for pointing this mistake out (and offering different solutions)! :)

Comment: should've also said I fixed my code by applying the first solution you recommended - thanks again!